# List of delimiters used in sqoop

Tags: oracle, hive, sqoop

I am sqooping data from oracle to hive, but the problem is the data contains all the delimiters due to which i am unable to use any delimiter available on keyboards.I tried '/001' also but that also not working.

Comment: i am talking about the delimiter used to separate fields

Answer (score 0):

the first idea that came into my head is spooling from oracle an xml file.

then you can use in hive a custom UDF to load that xml into hive
such as this :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+XPathUDF

Answer (score 0):

Delimiters may be specified as:

- \b (backspace)
- \n (newline)
- \r (carriage return)
- \t (tab)
- \" (double-quote)
- \' (single-quote)
- \ (backslash)
- \0 (NUL)

For more info you can check the below link:
http://archive-primary.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/sqoop-1.4.6-cdh5.10.1/SqoopUserGuide.html#_delimited_text_formats_and_field_and_line_delimiter_characters

---

Comment: The problem is most of them are part of data. I am using Ctrl+A, as this is a default delimiter for Hive to read data from files. Thanks for the help!